# SQL Injection Attacks

Tags: php, sql, sql-injection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to prevent SQL Injection in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

I'm new to PHP. I've heard a lot (and read about) SQL-injection attacks.
I have got accustomed to the following way of writing PHP code. Could someone tell me if this is prone to SQL attacks. Also, in what way can I improve this code against SQL-attacks?

```
<?php
    if($_POST['submit']){
        $email = protect($_POST['email']);
        $password = protect($_POST['password']);
        $md5password=MD5($password);
        if(!$email || !$password){
            echo '<span style="color: red;" /><center>You need to fill in your <b>User Name</b> and <b>Password</b>!</center></span>';
        }else{
            $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `employer` WHERE `email` = '".$email."'");
            $num = mysql_num_rows($res);
            if($num == 0){
                echo '<span style="color: red;" /><center>The <b>E Mail ID</b> you supplied does not exist!</center></span>';
            }else{
            $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `employer` WHERE `email` = '".$email."' AND `password` = '".$md5password."'");
            $num = mysql_num_rows($res);
            if($num == 0){
                echo '<span style="color: red;" /><center>The <b>Password</b> you supplied does not match the one for that E Mail ID!</center></span>';}else{
                $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
                $_SESSION['uid'] = $row['id'];
                echo "<center>You have successfully logged in!</center>";
                $time = date('U')+50;
                mysql_query("UPDATE `employer` SET `online` = '".$time."' WHERE `id` = '".$_SESSION['uid']."'");
                mysql_query("UPDATE employer (date) VALUES (NOW())");
                header('Location: loggedin_employer.php');
                }
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: You should stop using `mysql_*` functions. They're being deprecated. Instead use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (supported as of PHP 5.1) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (supported as of PHP 4.1). If you're not sure which one to use, [read this article](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use/).

Comment: You could improve it further by moving to [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and using prepared statements - it would also further protect you from the `mysql_*` functions becoming obsolete. PDO is the new *shiny* in PHP database connectivity.

Comment: If you want a critique of that particular code, you should probably be asking on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ … and provide a copy of the `protect` function you are calling.

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but MD5 is insufficient protection for passwords. See the [FAQ](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should stop using `mysql_*` functions. They're being deprecated. Instead use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (supported as of PHP 5.1) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (supported as of PHP 4.1). If you're not sure which one to use, [read this article](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use/).

Also, read this exchange: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)